# Unable to add class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am currently working on a dotnet web API with C# project, normally I was able to right click, Add=> Class then I can add a class. When the window that contains all the items popup I dont see the class option.

thank you

Close VS 2022 and run the VS installer as administrator, un-check and check the workload ‘.NET Desktop development’ to reinstall

Comment: Do you have the solution loaded in the Solution Explorer or it just the folder view?

Comment: yes the solution is loaded in the Solution Explorer

Comment: Hi, are you using .net or .net framework for your project. Under normal circumstances, projects of .net framework will not have this problem

Answer (score 0):

well, you want to add BOTH the desktop .net workflows and also of course the web based ones! (after all, doing asp.net work means you require the desktop bits and parts, right???

So, from vs tools->Get tools and features.

So, now we see/have this:

[image]

so, make sure all of the above are selected

Comment: [Ron Burgundy - I don't believe you.gifv] - you really don't need .NET Framework components to add a C# class to a project.

Comment: Well, for a asp.net web site applications, then some templates don't work unless you install the templates for asp.net. So, while one may be correct (you don't need the asp.net workflows? One should install them if one is going to work on any legacy web sites - boatloads of issues and problems will exist as a result.  In other words you have two choices: install the correct workflows and templates. Option 2: call your mother, and tell her this software thing not working for you, and it time to take up auto-repair, truck driving school, cooking school, or restaurant management school.